# Unable to link model to account in a single action

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2, usermanager

I have the following code in a user register action:

```
 var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db);
 var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);

 var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.email, Email = model.email };

 IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.password);
 userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "ARole");

AssociatedItem associatedItem = new AssociatedItem ();
associatedItem.email = model.email;

associatedItem.fullName = model.name;
associatedItem.account = user;
db.AssociatedItems.Add(associatedItem );
db.Entry(associatedItem ).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

The problem with this is that the user tries to be created again on `db.SaveChanges();` which causes an attempt at a user with a duplicate primary key value, which is not allowed. I can't associate the user with the `associatedItem` until the user is created. I have tried:

```
db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

before `db.SaveChanges();`, but the duplicate primary key issue still returns. Is there a simple way to associated a model class with a user when they register?

Comment: You can add the `AssociatedItem` when you create the `ApplicationUser`. It will create automatically all the relations.

Comment: Good idea. I would prefer though to create the relation in the other direction. Currently a 'magician' could be a user and also a 'wizard' could be a user. Thus the user is associated to both magician and wizard model classes. I do not have an ApplicationUser having a link to a magician nor a link to a wizard, because a user is either a wizard or a magician, but not both.